# Loop through a list of table rows until a row contains a particular string?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to loop through a list of lists of lists. For each list of list within the broader list, I want the loop to run UNTIL the row where the first column contains the string "Career."

So, for example, here is the list of list of lists that I am currently producing:

```
list_of_lists_of_lists = [[[Joe, 2, 3, 5, 6],
[Joe, 5, 6, 2, 5],
[Joe, 5, 7, 2, 2],
["Career, 24, 234, 2, 53]],
[[Brian, 2, 3, 5, 6],
[Brian, 5, 6, 2, 5],
[Brian, 5, 7, 2, 2],
["Career, 24, 234, 2, 53],
["String", 3, 2, 3, 4],
["Spaghetti, 3, 2, 2, 6]],
[[Tom, 2, 3, 5, 6],
[Tom, 5, 6, 2, 5],
[Tom, 5, 7, 2, 2],
["Career, 24, 234, 2, 53],
["String, 3, 2, 3, 2]]]
```

So again, in these examples, for each list of lists within the broader list, I want to NOT read in the row with "Career" and NOT read in anything below that row.

Note: I can't simply delete the last row because across there are multiple rows below the "Career" row, such as the rows with "String" and "Spaghetti."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `break` statement:

```
def my_funct(data):
   for i in data:
        if "Career" in i:
            break
        else:
            yield i

 print(list(my_funct(list_of_lists_of_lists)))
```

Output:

```
[[[Joe, 2, 3, 5, 6],
  [Joe, 5, 6, 2, 5],
  [Joe, 5, 7, 2, 2],
```

Note that in order for this solution to work your strings in the lists will have to be reformatted so that all are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @ThomasErnste glad to help!